# Double answers in the coin flip code

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I got an assignment to write a program that generates a random number. The program must then assign "heads" or "tails" to the number, and ask the user to guess whether it was heads or tails. If the user inputs the right answer, the program should respond "good guess!". If the user inputs the wrong answer, the program should respond "oops!".

My program doesn't work correctly.  No matter what the user guesses, it always outputs "good guess!".  When it selects "tails" and the user guesses incorrectly, it *additionally* outputs "oops!".  When the user guesses "heads" the program never outputs the "oops!" response at all.

This is what I wrote:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HeadsOrTails {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
        System.out.println ("Enter heads or tails");
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String flip = user_input.next();

        if (flip.equals ("heads") && (num1 == 1)) {
        }
        System.out.println ("good guess!");
        {
            if (flip.equals ("tails") && (num1 == 1)) {
                System.out.println ("Oops!");   
                if (flip.equals ("heads") && (num1 == 0)) {
                    System.out.println ("oops!");
                    if (flip.equals ("heads") && (num1 == 0)) {
                        System.out.println ("good guess!");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you indent the code properly? Then you'll see that your first print statement (for "good guess!") is outside the curly brackets, so it's always printed - not just when the if-condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

When properly indented, the code you posted looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HeadsOrTails {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num1 = (int)(Math.random() * 2);

        System.out.println ("Enter heads or tails");
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

        String flip = user_input.next();


        if (flip.equals ("heads") && (num1 == 1)) {
        }
        System.out.println ("good guess!"); {
        if (flip.equals ("tails") && (num1 == 1)) {
            System.out.println ("Oops!");   
            if (flip.equals ("heads") && (num1 == 0)) {
                System.out.println ("oops!");
                if (flip.equals ("heads") && (num1 == 0)) {
                    System.out.println ("good guess!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's now clear to see your code isn't doing quite what you want it to do.

As @Erwin Bolwidt correctly pointed out, the first "good guess" output is incorrectly placed outside of the if block.

The rest of the if blocks are all nested when they shouldn't be - they should also be if-then-else blocks.

Please take a look at this article: [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution to this problem would be to assign numerical values to heads and tails and check to see whether the numerical value equals 1 or 0.. It requires less if statements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class HeadsOrTails {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
        int guess = 0;

        System.out.println ("Enter heads or tails");
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

        if(user_input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("heads")) guess = 1;
        if(guess==num1){
            System.out.println("Good guess!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Oops!");
        }
    }
}
```

This solution does not take in to consideration that a user could enter something other than heads or tails, but for this simple program it doesn't seem necessary. Also, incase the user is writing in CAPS it is important to use `.equalsIgnoreCase("heads")` rather than `.equals("heads")` because the capitalization does not effect output.